# iOS Swift unit test result in unresolved identifier

Tags: ios, unit-testing, swift

Simple function in swift for testing:

```
func testExample() {
    var tagname = "someClass()"
    var logger = Device("", "") //unresolved identifier

    XCTAssert(true, "Pass")
}
```

Even after I import my module with "import ", I still cannot use classes from my module. Also though I might have messed something up in the project, but NONE of my sample projects will let me use module classes.

Seems like it should work but might have broken in beta 2.

EDIT: fixed it
The IDE didn't pick up the check for the param names. Seems Xcode is still a tad iffy

Answer (score 20):

I hit the same issue today, not sure if this is only available recently - rather than using `import TARGET_NAME` in your test file and/or declaring your classes/methods as `public`, you can add your file to your Tests target via XCode's `File Inspector`.

`Cmd` + `Opt` + `1` to show it while in any file, and check the box under `Target Membership` for your Tests Target.

[image: File Inspector - Target Membership]

You may need to rebuild.... `Cmd` + `b`.

Should this be specific to my system.... I'm running Xcode 6.3 beta 1, and testing via Quick + Nimble, both installed with the latest cocoapods beta.

Comment: Tried a lot of methods, this is the only one that worked.

Comment: Be careful if you add the files like this and you also use the ```@testable import``` feature, because you'll end up with "Cannot assign value of type 'X' to type 'X'" errors. See https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/24474. Also, "clean" seems to be funny sometimes. I was getting "unresolved identifier" after I removed the files and switched to @testable import and cleaning wasn't helping. After modifying one file, the errors disappeared...

Comment: The file where you are receiving the error is probably added as Target Membership in your Tests or UITests targets, while the code that's failing is in a file that's not added there. Removing the Tests membership worked for me, but I assume both files must have the same Target Memberships

Answer (score 11):

The problem for me was that I had non-alphanumerical characters in my main target name.

I had to import it the following way (Note the special `@testable annotation`)

`@testable import my_tutorial_app`

Answer (score 7):

It seems that in Xcode 6 Beta 4 you need to declare public classes and methods as "public". Example:

```
public class Device {
    public init(...) {
    }

    public func myMethod(...) {
    }
}
```

Now they are accessible from the swift test class.

Comment: That did it. Is this just a temporary work around ? or is this how things are meant to work. Tests defined alongside a project should not require this. (I can understand if these were acceptance tests against a module).

Comment: You can use "@testable import Foo" lets you use public or "internal access" functions/classes.  That way you can test things without making them all the way public.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and discovered that it works if I call it like this:

```
SuperStructName.StructName
```