# Writing a unit-test for a class extension in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, xctest

I'm attempting to write a unit test for a class extension in Swift. The class extension itself will present a `UIAlert` with a specified title and message as such:

```
extension UIViewController {

    func presentAlert(title: String, message : String) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

I created a file for my unit test containing the code below:

```
import XCTest

class AlertTest: XCTestCase {

    func testAlert() {

        let alert = presentAlert("Presented Alert", "This is an Alert!")

    }

}
```

However, I keep getting an error of `"Use of unresolved identifier 'presentAlert'"`. I tried adding `public` to my extension after consulting this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24477251/ios-swift-unit-test-result-in-unresolved-identifier):

`public func presentAlert(title: String, message : String)`

but still no luck. Anyone have some insight?

**EDIT**

Based on the answer by @hkgumbs, this is my current code for my alert extension:

```
import Foundation

protocol Presentable {}

extension UIViewController {

    public func presentAlert(title: String, message : String) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

In the view controller, where I want to show the alert, this would still be the correct way to call my alert, correct?

```
self.presentAlert("Invalid URL", message: "Please try again")
```

Secondly, based on your comment, this is what I what I understand by calling `Presentable` on a dummy value, but it's incorrect as `SomethingPresentable` has no member `PresentAlert`. Where I am going wrong in my understanding?

```
func testAlert() {

    let app = XCUIApplication()

    struct SomethingPresentable: Presentable {}

    SomethingPresentable.presentAlert("Presented Alert", message: "This is an Alert!")

    XCTAssert(app.alerts["Presented Alert"].exists)
    app.alerts["Presented Alert"].tap();

}
```

**EDIT 2**
@hkgumbs, based on your newest comment, this is what I have for the extension:

```
import Foundation

protocol Presentable {}

extension Presentable {

    func presentAlert(title: String, message : String) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

And this is how I'm trying to call it from my ViewController:

```
Presentable.presentAlert("Invalid URL", message: "Please try again")
```

However, I get an error of "Use of instance member `presentAlert` on type `Self`; did you mean to use a variable of type `Self` instead?"

Then, I'm guessing this is how the test would look?

```
func testAlert() {

    let app = XCUIApplication()

    struct SomethingPresentable: Presentable {}

    SomethingPresentable.presentAlert("Presented Alert", message: "This is an Alert!")

    XCTAssert(app.alerts["Presented Alert"].exists)
    app.alerts["Presented Alert"].tap();

}
```

Comment: Your extension is on `UIViewController` so you need to call it on a `UIViewController`.  The way you are calling it doesn't match the declaration either.

Comment: @dan Thank you for catching that typo...I just fixed it in the question. What would calling it on a ViewController in a unit test look like?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [@dan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1395203/dan) alluded to, you need to call it from *an instance* of the `UIViewController`. Usually you don't want to instantiate framework objects in your tests if you can avoid it, so here are some options to avoid that:

1. **Make `presentAlert` static so that you can just `UIViewController.presentAlert`**
2. **Make `presentAlert` a free function (don't put it in the extension)**
3. **Extend a protocol instead – I think this is the cleanest option**

---

```
protocol Presentable {}

extension Presentable {
    func presentAlert(title: String, message : String) { /* ... */ }
}
```

Then, whenever you need it you can `extension UIViewController: Presentable {}`. And in your tests, you can just use a dummy class. The added benefit with this approach is that you can reuse that function on any type if needed, without globally exposing it when you don't.

**Addendum**

When we extend the protocol we are saying "anything that implements this protocol will get this method for free." The trick here is that this protocol is empty and, therefore, very easy to "implement."

```
extension YourViewController: Presentable {}
```

Comment: This is starting to make some sense to me, thank you. Two questions for you:

1) If I make the extension a protocol instead, how would I call that from my view controller? Currently, calling the extension looks like this: 

                            self.presentAlert("Invalid URL", message: "Please try again")


2) I'm not exactly sure what you mean by using a dummy class to call this protocol from my tests...can you elaborate further? 

Thank you --- still trying to get used to some of Swift's intricacies!

Comment: happy to accept this answer; just needing a little more understanding...thank you!

Comment: @narner sure!
1) If you extend this protocol then you will have access to it in the same way: `extension YourViewController: Presentable {}`.

2) Same idea for making a dummy value in your tests: `struct SomethingPresentable: Presentable {}`. Then call `presentAlert` on that instead of the `ViewController`.

Comment: I'm *almost* there I think....I made an edit to my original post. Would you mind taking one last look? Thank you for your help and patience!!!

Comment: @narner almost indeed! So instead of `extension UIViewController` you want `extension Presentable`. That will fix your test.

And then in order to have the functionality on the ViewController you need that line from my previous comment.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of fully understanding this...I made one more edit to my post based on your comments. Thank you again for your help!!!!

Comment: @narner All you need to do is change `Presentable.presentAlert` to `self.presentAlert` (since you have already declared your ViewController as `Presentable`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120892/discussion-between-narner-and-hkgumbs).