# Target membership fix for unresolved identifier when testing framework

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks

I have recently created a framework with unit testing. 
The problem is that when Im trying to launch tests, Im getting an error:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'SessionManager'

I discovered that problem may be fixed by setting target membership for SessionManager to both targets: framework and tests.

But the question is:

> How they can work separately?

Got this in framework seed:

```
//  SessionManager.swift
//  URLSessionKit

import Foundation

public class SessionManager {
    var name : String
    public init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

and this in tests:

```
//  URLSessionKitTests.swift
//  URLSessionKitTests

import XCTest
@testable import URLSessionKit

class URLSessionKitTests: XCTestCase {

    func testExample() {
        SessionManager(name: "someName")
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24477251/ios-swift-unit-test-result-in-unresolved-identifier for some ideas.

Comment: None of these worked. However the problem was in cleaning DerivedData after I corrected target imports.